# How to display a picture behind a div block

Tags: html, css, svg

I have his svg object of magnifier:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <div>
        <input title="Поиск" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 60px" type="text" class="_2z-tgin">
        <button class="_1PEaSbT" type="submit" style="margin-top: 3px;margin-right: 5px">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="21px" height="20px" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
                            viewBox="0 0 154 148.08"
                             xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                             enable-background="new 0 0 96 96">
               <defs>
                    <style type="text/css">
                                .search {stroke: #000000;stroke-width:10.03;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
                                .fil0 {fill:none}
                    </style>
               </defs>
               <g id="Слой_x0020_1">
                    <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
                    <g id="_1195129152">
                         <path class="fil0 search" d="M108.31 86.58c-2.19,3.69 -4.86,7.16 -8.03,10.33 -20.48,20.48 -53.69,20.48 -74.17,0 -20.48,-20.48 -20.48,-53.68 0,-74.16 20.48,-20.48 53.69,-20.49 74.17,-0.01 14,14.01 20.24,43.25 8.03,63.84z"/>
                               <line class="fil0 search" x1="101.83" y1="98.47" x2="143.49" y2= "140.12" />
                    </g>
               </g>
           </svg>
       </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Also I have next dropdown menu that shows by hovering on the cart:
[image]

But as you can see magnifier shows over my dropdown menu. It should be behind it becouse it is a part of search bar.
[image]

Can I fix this somehow? I tried to change svg object on image but it didn't help. Thank you.

Comment: Where have you added the SVG in your code?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `magnifier shows over my dropdown menu. Can I fix this somehow?` Fix in which way? Where is it supposed to be?

Comment: since you are using svg elements, why not use `<text>` object to hold the `text`. That should format it to display inline

Comment: post parent node please

Comment: Magnifier should be behind dropdown menu.

Comment: Have you checked the z-index values of the elements in question? Maybe that could be the issue

Comment: @SergeiPetrov: Try adding `z-index` and also `position` too.